# Can not compile xUnit test classes (via mono) to exe file, using mcs command

Tags: mono, xunit.net, .net-framework-version, msys2

I am using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) in order to run C# project (in `.NET Framework`) in `Linux` environment on `Windows` machine.

My projects are placed in the path: `D:\MyRootPath` and there I have two separate solutions:

- `D:\MyRootPath\MainProject` - this is my main project;
- `D:\MyRootPath\xUnitProject`- this is a separate solution that contains project that I use for unit testing with [xUnit.net](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/visual-studio) framework (for `.NET Framework`);

**Building main project (working sample)**

Inside of `D:\MyRootPath\MainProject` I have a sample class `D:\MyRootPath\MainProject\HelloWorld.cs`:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }
}
```

When I want to build this via `mono`, to create an `.exe` file and run it, I am using the following commands inside of the `MSYS2` console (this approach is working well):

```
mcs /d/MyRootPath/MainProject/HelloWorld.cs
mono /d/MyRootPath/MainProject/HelloWorld.exe
```

**Building xunit project (need help here)**

Inside of the xUnitProject, I have many classes, where each class represent a test case (and each test case have reference to the main project - `MainProject.dll`). One example of test case is `D:\MyRootPath\xUnitProject\SampleRectangle.cs`:

```
using MainProject;
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace xUnitProject
{
    public class SimpleRectangle
    {
        [Fact]
        public void simpleRectangle()
        {
            //this content is irrelevant to the question, I have a few Assert checks
            Assert.Equal("someVariable", someVariable);
            Assert.Equal("someOtherVarialble", someOtherVarialble);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I need to build this via `mono`, to create an `.exe` file and run it. Since I have many classes like  `SimpleRectangle`, I need to run them all and to have separate `.exe` files for each.

So I am trying to build the test classes with the following (similar as above working example):

```
mcs /d/MyRootPath/xUnitProject/SampleRectangle.cs -r:/d/MyRootPath/xUnitProject/bin/Debug/MainProject.dll:/d/MyRootPath/xUnitProject/bin/Debug/xunit.core.dll
```

where I had to add `-r` flag, since it points to the `.dll` files that are used.

The output that I got is:

```
D:/MyRootPath/xUnitProject/SimpleRectangle.cs: error CS0012: The type `System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
D:\MyRootPath\xUnitProject\bin\Debug\xunit.core.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
D:/MyRootPath/xUnitProject/SimpleRectangle.cs: error CS0103: The name `Assert' does not exist in the current context
D:/MyRootPath/xUnitProject/SimpleRectangle.cs: error CS0103: The name `Assert' does not exist in the current context
error CS5001: Program `SimpleRectangle.exe' does not contain a static `Main' method suitable for an entry point
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: Migrate to .NET Core and then simply `dotnet test`.

Comment: @LexLi that is not an option. Net Core requires Visual Studio 2017 SDK and my solution should have an approach that aims to cover as much as possible development environments. For example, my current approach works even for Visual Studio 2015 and I need to keep this.

Comment: .NET Core development only requires .NET Core SDK, so I wonder where you learned that VS 2017 SDK is required. You don't even need VS, as a suitable editor (like VSCode) plus command line is enough. You cannot really stick to VS2015/2017 while more and more .NET dependencies from NuGet move towards .NET Standards (requires .NET Core SDK as well).

Comment: @LexLi I am using mono in msys2 and I don't have access to dotnet command in my environment

Comment: .NET Core allows you to cross compile Linux binaries directly on Windows, via `dotnet publish` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained and all you need is just .NET Core SDK. For Windows 10 users, WSL is also an option to run Linux distributions without much trouble. Once you get used to the new tooling, probably you don't want to look back.

Comment: @LexLi I see your point, but I am using msys2 and mono, as my linux environment. There, I simply don't have access to dotnet command and for the whole day I can not figure out how to make it working :)